# How to detect which 3d object has been touched?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Assume I have 3 cubes in random location/rotation that are visible in the viewport. I want to be able to detect if which of the cube has been touched if I touch ( or click on emulator) a specific cube. If I just touch empty space instead of a cube, this should also be properly detected. I know there is onTouchEvent callback that you over-ride on a View but this only gives me x,y coordinate of where the touch occurred. I am looking for OpenGL-ES based solution and more specifically for Java based Android application.

Answer (score 2):

THere could be several objects (or none) that are on that x / y coordinate. You should find them all, and then if there are any, check the z-coordinate to see which one is the closest to the viewport (and so the one that was touched).

Answer (score 0):

Often wondered about best way to do this without glSelect()... this answer looks good: [iPhone OpenGL ES - How to Pick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540447/iphone-opengl-es-how-to-pick/2558935#2558935)

(You can ignore the fact it's an iOS question... the OpenGL ES API is the same on both platforms AFAIK).

Comment: Unfortunately I could not follow the C based solution there and how to change to Java based Android app.

Comment: As stated in the question I am looking for Java based Android solution.

Comment: Try this then: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/nSv1Pjp5jLY ... its an Android implementation of gluUnproject() which is pretty much exactly what you want.